# Node.js mikeal/request module - Garbled non-utf8 website (Shift_JIS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, request, shift-jis

I am trying to access a non utf-8 website using request module. Response is garbled for this request.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.alc.co.jp/', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the web page.
  }
});
```

Even after setting the encoding option to Shift_JIS I am seeing garbled Japanese text.

Comment: https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite I think you can use this to decode SHIFT_JIS buffer into UTF-8 string.

Comment: found another for Node here. I'm going to try and make it into a Meteor package. https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js

Comment: that looks good too @Jerry

Answer (score 6):

You need to do the conversion yourself. The example code below uses node-iconv.

```
    var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
    var request = require('request');
    request({
      uri: 'http://www.jalan.net/',
      encoding: null,
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        body = new Iconv('shift_jis', 'utf-8').convert(body).toString();
        console.log(body); // Print the web page.
      }
    });
```

1. The `encoding: null` parameter asks `request` not to convert the `Buffer` (a byte array) into `String` yet.
2. We pass this buffer to `Iconv` for converting into another `Buffer` of UTF-8 encoding.
3. Now this `Buffer` is good for being converted into a String.

(BTW, http://www.alc.co.jp has switched to UTF-8, so I substituted with another site.)

Comment: Thanks Alan! This should help some people. Cheers!